How to create a responsive hamburger menu and across all devices?
I'm trying to build a simple responsive navbar can anybody please help with it , need a hamburger menu and target for all types of devices .I tried doing it but couldn't do it. I need help with trying to create a responsive navbar. I'm trying to make it so when the web page gets smaller than a hamburger menu will appear and then that can be clicked for a drop down menu of the tabs. If anyone can help me with this it will be appreciated.


body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  gap: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav button {
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: .5em 1.5em;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: .5em;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  /* color: black; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li span {
  /* display: block; */
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0) translateY(30px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 3px;
  /* margin: ; */
}


/* Now For Hover Effects */

nav ul li:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}


/* now animation effect for logo */

nav .Logo {
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: block;
  animation-name: ScaleAnimtions;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes ScaleAnimtions {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
<header>
  <nav>
    <span class="Logo">Logo</span>
    <ul>
      <!-- span tags for animations effect on hover -->
      <li>Home <span></span></li>
      <li>About <span></span></li>
      <li>Contact <span></span></li>
      <li>Services <span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </nav>
</header>




Please show us what you have tried. In particular what @media query you are using and how you want to show the hamburger icon (as an image or drawn with CSS), BTW, there’s lots of help with this already out there if you search. Have a go at coding it, and come back here if still stuck.

Possible dupe

Have you done this tutorial?

This question is similar to: Hamburger menu responsiveness issue. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
